# Laravel of Controller Function Should be Compatible with Base Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I created a new route link to Users Controller validate function in web.php. I also create a function on Users Controller called validate. Other routes has no problem other than this.

Error

```
(1/1) ErrorException
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\UsersController::validate(App\$id) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = Array, array $customAttributes = Array)
```

Web routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'can:see-admin'], function () {
        Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' => ['index', 'destroy', 'create', 'validate']]);
        Route::post('users/store', 'UsersController@store')->name('user.store');
        Route::get('users/{user}/impersonate', 'UsersController@impersonate')->name('users.impersonate');
        Route::get('users/{id}', 'UsersController@validate')->name('users.validate'); //this is the new route that is created
    });
```

Users controller

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function validate($id)
    {
        $validation = User::validate($image);

        return back();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the requested url shown in address bar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: Don't use this Method name, it is be used by `validator`.

2: Try to use another action nameBecause you have missing the `Request $request` in your action, try to change it like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request; // Remember import Request
...
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function validateUser(Request $request, $id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Still the same error exist. ```Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\UsersController::validate(App\Http\Controllers\Request $request, $id) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = Array, array $customAttributes = Array)```

Comment: you need to import `Request` in your controller before the `class`, I have updated.

Comment: Ya still the same ```Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\UsersController::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $id) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, array $rules, array $messages = Array, array $customAttributes = Array)```

Comment: @zy oh I see, don't use this Method name, it is be used by validator. try to use another action name.

Comment: Thanks. it works. How do you know this method name is used?

Comment: @zy your error msg says that the parameters need to be compatible with  `validate(...$rules` and `$message` etc.., and this is `validator`'s parameters.